# Does a differentiable everywhere function have a continuous derivative?

Tags: calculus

If a function $f$ defined on $[a,b]$ and *differentiable everywhere*, does it mean that its derivative $f'(x)$ is continuous everywhere on $[a,b]$?

My understanding is 'yes'. Because if there were 'a gap' in $f'(x)$, we could integrate back to $f(x)$ and show that where the gap is, there would be a sharp "angle" where $f(x)$ is not differentiable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not necessarily. The standard example is
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
x^2\sin\dfrac1x & x\ne0,\\0 & x=0.
\end{cases}
$$
$f'(0)=0$, but $\lim_{x\to0}f'(x)$ does not exist.

Comment: Can there be other examples? I found $x^2\cos{\frac1x}$, but can't think of any other.

Comment: You can try $(x-x_0)^a\sin((x-x_0)^b)$, $(x-x_0)^a\cos((x-x_0)^b)$ for certain values of $a$ and $b$ and any $x_0$. Then you can combine them.

Comment: Thanks, but would there be some other form...?

Comment: I think $a(x-x_0)^{m+1}\sin^p\left(\frac1{(x-x_0)^m}\right) + b(x-x_1)^{n+1}\cos^q\left(\frac1{(x-x_1)^n}\right)$ work all as you said, but still wondering if there's other form.